# Devexpress XAF New Security System - Criteria in "SecuritySystemObjectPermissionsObject" Class

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

I am using New Security System in my XAF Project. I have created custom security classes "ExtendedSystemSecurityRole" and "SecuritySystemUser". In Updater class I have created a role named "G1" and its permissions as follows. But when running, User "John" Can not see the "Buyer" form.

```
ExtendedSecuritySystemRole basicUserRole = ObjectSpace.FindObject<ExtendedSecuritySystemRole>(new BinaryOperator("Name", "G1"));
        if (basicUserRole == null)             
        {
            basicUserRole = ObjectSpace.CreateObject<ExtendedSecuritySystemRole>();
            basicUserRole.Name = "G1";
            SecuritySystemTypePermissionObject userTypePermission =
                ObjectSpace.CreateObject<SecuritySystemTypePermissionObject>();
            userTypePermission.TargetType = typeof(Buyer);
            SecuritySystemObjectPermissionsObject currentUserObjectPermission =
                ObjectSpace.CreateObject<SecuritySystemObjectPermissionsObject>();

            currentUserObjectPermission.Criteria = "[Active] = True";
            currentUserObjectPermission.AllowNavigate = true;
            currentUserObjectPermission.AllowRead = true;
            userTypePermission.ObjectPermissions.Add(currentUserObjectPermission);
            basicUserRole.TypePermissions.Add(userTypePermission);
        }
        ExtendedSecuritySystemUser userJohn =
            ObjectSpace.FindObject<ExtendedSecuritySystemUser>(
            new BinaryOperator("UserName", "John"));
        if (userJohn == null)
        {
            userJohn = ObjectSpace.CreateObject<ExtendedSecuritySystemUser>();
            userJohn.UserName = "John";
            userJohn.SetPassword("");
            userJohn.Roles.Add(basicUserRole);
        }
```

Comment: Did you forget to make userJohn active? Does it work if you remove the criteria? The best place for DevExpress support is the [Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

Comment: "John" is active. Yes it works without criteria. DevExpress support center answers only to registered users (with a valid license).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your criteria is saying `Buyer.Active = True` not `ExtendedSecuritySystemUser.Active = true`.

You *could* [create your own function operator](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#xaf/CustomDocument3480) `IsCurrentUserActive()`

It would be simpler to use a `ViewController` for this. Something like:

```
public class InactiveUsersController : ViewController
{
    public InactiveUsersController()
    {
        this.TargetViewNesting = Nesting.Any;
        this.TargetViewType = ViewType.ListView;
        this.TargetObjectType = typeof(Buyer);
    }

    protected override void OnActivated()
    {
        base.OnActivated();
        ListView listView = View as ListView;
        listView.CollectionSource.Criteria.Remove("InactiveUserFilter"); // clear the filter

        var currentUser = SecuritySystem.CurrentUser as ExtendedSecuritySystemUser;
        if (!currentUser.Active)
        {
            // return empty list if user is inactive
            listView.CollectionSource.Criteria.Add("InactiveUserFilter", CollectionSource.EmptyCollectionCriteria); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But what I need to do has nothing to do with ExtendedSecuritySystemUser. I just want the security system to understand the criteria, it doesn't matter what I do write. If I want to filter the Buyer type, I would use its attributes like [Active] or the others. But the problem is that the security system does not throw any exception and it doesn't show any reasonable output.

Comment: Which object has the 'Active' property? Buyer or User? Currently, your criteria seems to be returning zero rows. You could use the same criteria syntax with an `XPCollection` to check the result set.

Comment: Buyer has an "Active" property.

Comment: Ok in that case, you need two separate permissions objects. John should be able to Navigate to the list view regardless of any criteria. So you need a permission object with `AllowNavigate` but with no criteria. But he should not be able to read rows that are not active. So add another separate permission object for `AllowRead` with the criteria.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes your solution worked. But I'm so sorry that Devexpress support center has nothing about this. Thanks again :)